# Sudoku Solver Java(not working like its supposed to)

Tags: java, arraylist, sudoku

I am trying to make a Sudoku solver in java but it just doesn't seem to work.
My intent is to fill a 2-D ArrayList with Integer Arrays containing possible solutions. So, for every cell it checks for the numbers that can be placed into that cell. It checks for Row, Column, and the square it is in. If there is only one possible solution, then that is kept as a final answer. The code should run until all the Integer Arrays have a size of one, i.e they have reached a final answer.
Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import static sun.security.krb5.Confounder.intValue;

    public class SudokuBoard {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> col = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();
    int[] possible = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> row = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Integer integer = /**(int) (Math.random() * 10);*/scan.nextInt();
            nums.add(integer);
            row.add(nums);
        }
        col.add(row);
    }
    printArray(col);
    boolean step = true;

    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> place = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> row = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Integer integer = 0;
            nums.add(integer);
            row.add(nums);
        }
        place.add(row);
    }
    int count = 0;
    while(step) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
        step = false;
        for (int h = 0; h < col.size(); h++) {                   //main logic for the code
            for (int k = 0; k < col.get(h).size(); k++) {
                boolean canAdd = false;
                if (col.get(h).get(k).get(0).intValue() == 0) {
                    ArrayList<Integer> last = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                        ArrayList<Integer> left = toCompare(col, "h", h);
                        ArrayList<Integer> down = toCompare(col, "v", k);
                        ArrayList<Integer> square = toCompare(col, h, k);
                        boolean inL = false;
                        boolean inD = false;
                        boolean inS = false;
                        for (int j = 0; j < left.size(); j++) {
                            if (i == left.get(j).intValue()) {
                                inL = true;
                            }
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < down.size(); j++) {
                            if (i == down.get(j).intValue()) {
                                inD = true;
                            }
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < square.size(); j++) {
                            if (i == square.get(j).intValue()) {
                                inS = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!inL && !inD && !inS) {
                            last.add(i);
                            canAdd = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(canAdd){
                        //last.add(0);
                        col.get(h).set(k, last);}
                    if(col.get(h).get(k).size() != 1 )//|| col.get(h).get(k).get(0).intValue() == 0)
                    {
                        step = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    printArray(col);
    System.out.println(count);


}

public static ArrayList<Integer> toCompare(ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> list, String type, int row) {
    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (type.equals("h")) { // Checks the horizontal for used numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (/**list.get(row).get(i).size() == 1 && */list.get(row).get(i).get(0).intValue() != 0) {
                ints.add(list.get(row).get(i).get(0));
            }
        }
    } else if (type.equals("v")) {//checks the vertical for used numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (/**list.get(i).get(row).size() == 1 &&*/ list.get(i).get(row).get(0).intValue() != 0) {
                ints.add(list.get(i).get(row).get(0).intValue());
            }
        }
    }
    return ints;
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> toCompare(ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> list, int row, int col) {
    int c = (int) (col / 3); //checks the square for used numbers.
    int r = (int) (row / 3);
    ArrayList<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = r; i < r + 3; i++) {
        for (int j = c; j < c + 3; j++) {
            if (list.get(i).get(j).get(0).intValue() != 0/** && list.get(i).get(j).size() == 1*/) {
                ret.add(list.get(i).get(j).get(0).intValue());
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public static void printArray(ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> col) { //prints out the array.
    for (int i = 0; i < col.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col.get(i).size(); j++) {
            System.out.print("" + (col.get(i).get(j).get(0).intValue()));
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

I am not that experienced and I also tried debugging it. But, it just won't work as intended.

I have seen code online already on how to do it, but I think it is better to learn using your own way.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: What's actually going wrong?  Are you getting an error?  What is it doing that you don't expect?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I wasn't more clear. There is no error, rather It just doesn't solve it. I think the logic is correct, but the implementation might be wrong.

Comment: What input are you providing?  What output are you expecting?  What output are you getting?

Comment: The scanner scans a real sudoku problem that I got off the internet(it has the solution), Then it tries to solve it, but not all squares are filled and the ones that are done right.

Comment: As a side note, it doesn't actually scan the page, rather an array of values it uses to fill the board.(And 0 stands for an empty space).

Comment: Take a look at http://www.baeldung.com/java-sudoku for an alternative solution.

Comment: As I said, I want to try doing this without prewritten code. I only want to find a way to modify mine.

Comment: I don't think you'll solve any sudoku, other than the very easiest ones, just by repeatedly filling in squares that have only one possible value.  It's no surprise that this algorithm leaves the solution unfinished.